# A friend of mine seems to believe that E=mgc. He believes that gravity and light are the same. That gravity is just photons not moving. Silly I’m sure

Tags: gravity, visible-light

I don’t know how to frame the question because I lack understanding of physics. But it doesn’t make sense to me when he says E=mc2 is wrong or incomplete and that his formula of E=mgc is the definitive answer. Everyone I’ve asked just laughs at it. My friend claims that physicists will deny it due to it rewriting the fabric of our understanding of physics. Does anyone agree with him here?

Comment: $g$ is the gravitational acceleration close to the surface of the Earth, it is not a universal constant like $c$, just an accident. Therefore, the claimed formula has no universal value. Also, $mgc$ is a "power", not an "energy".

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147964/discussion-on-question-by-justin-hodge-a-friend-of-mine-seems-to-believe-that-e); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 6):

This formula just doesn't make any physical sense.

It doesn't even have correct units. Energy is always measured in
$$[E] = \left[\frac{1}{2} m v^2\right] = M L^2 T^{-2}$$
where $M$ means mass, $L$ length, and $T$ time.

The formula of your friend has units
$$ [m g c] = M L T^{-2} L T^{-1} = M L^2 T^{-3} \neq [E]$$